# Python Pandas df.xs() Unable to Assign Variables in For Loop

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I am working on some report automation with a pandas pivot table. I am attempting to loop through keys and items in a dictionary with the goal of assigning a new variable for each key in that dictionary while using the associated value as my index identifier.

I am able to perform the following with success:

```
AlyssaS_LastName = piv.xs(('Alyssa S. Lastname'), level=0)
```

The above code will spit out a pivot table showing relevant metrics for the employee just fine. I have about 80 for of these pivot tables to generate and I run into a problem when I try to loop through by dictionary, formatted as followed:

```
 d = {'AlessandraR_LastName': 'Alessandra R. LastName',
      'AlyssaS_LastName': 'Alyssa S. LastName',
      ...}
```

When I enter the following code, I get a syntax error:

```
for k, v in d.items():
"{0}".format(k) = piv.xs(("{0}".format(v)), level=0)
```

Error below:

```
  File "<ipython-input-91-24de6622c810>", line 2
"{0}".format(k) = piv.xs(("{0}".format(v)), level=0).copy()
^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you're trying to assign `format(k)` which is a function call. What you really want to do is assign to the *result* of the function call.

Try doing it on two different lines, e.g.

```
_ = "{0}".format(k)
_ = whatever
```

Though you're trying to assign to a `str` here, is that what you want to do do?

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I do want to assign the string of the dict key to the variable name. How would I do that exactly if I have to assign a static variable name to the .format() function call? I guess the crux of my issue is that I don't know how to make those variables with in the for loop dynamic.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here, can you give an example please?

Comment: @AndyG to assign values to a key in a dictionary `d`, you do `d[key] = value`, not `key = value`

Comment: @ColinRicardo - used your advise and was able to come up with a solution that tied each new variable to my dictionary as follows:

    `for k, v in d.items():
        d["{0}".format(k)] = ["{0}".format(v), piv.xs(("{0}".format(v)), 
        level=0)]`

Comment: Glad I could help! :)